# Struggling to implement this simple algorithm for ECG wave delineation

Tags: python, hilbert-transform, ecg

I'm trying my best but my maths isn't good enough to implement the algorithm as outlined in [this paper](http://jamesphoward.com/04352347.pdf) in python. It for detecting the onset and offset of a wave on an ECG, and it's using a well validated method.

My data is in a numpy array.

The steps it uses are:

A. Computation of the envelope of the ECG

B. Computation of the auxiliary signal

C. Windowing

I think I've got step A. done:

```
def calculate_qrs_envelope(self):
    self.hilbert = np.imag(hilbert(self.lead_data['y']))
    self.envelope = np.sqrt(np.add(self.lead_data['y'],self.hilbert))
    self.plot(x=self.lead_data['x'], y=self.envelope, pen='b')
```

Where my data is stored in `lead_data['y']`.

If I plot it, it looks correct (I can't show the picture here as I don't have enough karma).

And I'm confident that I won't struggle with C.

However, B is difficult. It says in the paper:
[image]

I can calculate AS using a simple derivative, as so:

```
def calculate_auxiliary_signal(self):
    self.aux_sig = np.append([0],np.multiply(2,pow(np.diff(self.envelope),2)))
    self.plot(x=self.lead_data['x'], y=self.aux_sig, pen='g')
```

But I don't understand how to do it with regards to what it says about the parabolic fit.

My sampling frequency is 100 Hz.

Would anyone be able to give me a hand with this maths? It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any sense on the formula exposed in the paper, but as is, the expression is just a derivative approximation, with $r=r_0$.

$$
x'_k=\frac 1{10}(2(x_{k+2r}-x_{k-2r})+(x_{k+r}-x_{k-r}))\\
y_k=2(x'_k)^2
$$

That is what the paper say.

That is, you have a signal $x$, and you calculate $x'$ as a moving average, taking samples above and below the current index.

For any given signal $x:x_1...x_n$, you will straightforwardly be able to calculate $x'$ and $y$ without trouble.

Comment: Ah sorry yes, so it's essentially saying they estimated a derivative using that equation. That seems a strange way to do it, I actually wonder if a Savitzky–Golay filter might be better...

Comment: Sure, it is quite pathological just to take *two* distances for the derivative. very absurd. A SG filter would be the proper replacement if you will end it in a paper.